# Is there any standard implementation of the "trivial constraint", or "object class"?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, constraint-kinds

I want just

```
class Trivial t
instance Trivial t
```

This is of course useless in Haskell 98 since you can just omit the constraint; but with `ConstraintKinds` we can have explicitly required arguments of kind `* -> Constraint`. Ideally, I would like to just define this as an "anonymous type-level function" `\type a -> ()`, but that's evidently not possible.

What should I do, use something predefined or just define that class locally right where I need it (as nobody will need to access it because the instance is universal, that seems quite ok as well)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @WW.: right now, [`type (-->) = ConstrainedCategory (->) Trivial`](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories/blob/f2f06b52d0e8cf18cd84d4d9bd0c50247109652d/examples/Invertible.hs#L35). There, it is basically just needed to avoid a conflicting MPTC-FunDep of the non-endo–functor instance of the optionally-invertible function type, but I intend to make more general use of it.

Comment: I believe that `() :: Constraint` is the trivial constraint.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: sure that's the trivial `Constraint`, but _type constraints_ are in fact of kind `* -> Constraint`. Which can't be defined quite as easily as `(\_ -> ()) :: a -> ()`.

Comment: ah, sorry for not reading your question carefully

Comment: In that case, I’d say: There are no type level lambdas, and I don’t find anything suitable in the libraries, so you will have to define it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this appears to be quite popular, I finally pushed such a trivial-constraint class [to a Hackage package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint).

```
import Data.Constraint.Trivial

id' :: Unconstrained t => t -> t
id' = id
```